# How to convert OpenOffice ODF files to HTML

Tags: html, openoffice.org, odf

I have some ODF files with math formulas and I need to render them...or else the boss will fire me (lol).

Please, is there any way to do this ? or they can only be rendered in OpenOffice ?

Comment: To make it more clear, I have created a File->New->Formula and put in text "sum from {r in setR } p(r)" which displays fine, but I'd need this in an HTML page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it's better to save the document as a pdf and convert it from the pdf-file instead

Convert with a tool like
http://www.pdfonline.com/convert-pdf-to-html/
or
http://www.somepdf.com/some-pdf-to-html-converter.html

Comment: Also, http://zamzar.com allows odt files to be converted directly to html - this is probably the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Open the File in OpenOffice.org (download at http://www.openoffice.org if needed) and use "Save As..." and select HTML as the output format. The Formulas will be rendered to images which are referenced in the resulting HTML.

There is currently no other solution that will render the formulas appropriately.

Comment: "Save as..." does not give this option. Formats supported are .sxm, .smf, .mml.

Comment: I was assuming that the document in question is a Text document (.odt). When you click on Save As... the format drop-down will contain an entry named "HTML Document (OpenOffice.org Writer) (html)"

Comment: You might need to make sure that teh formula editor is not activated, maybe it tries to save a single formula instead of the entire document. This doesn't happen in my version though.

Comment: I tried saving an .odt file as HTML, and the formatting was not preserved correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the formula file into a Writer document (Insert -> Object -> OLE Object -> Create from file).

Then save that document as HTML and the formula will be integrated into the generated HTML as an image.

Answer (score 0):

In OpenOffice Writer, select Insert, Object, Formula and then paste in your code in the lower window.  Save as HTML and it will open in your browser

Comment: How is this answer radically different from the other, *older* answers that insert a formula then `Save as...` HTML?